# unhandled exception has occurred in your application error comes when installing setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, odbc, ssms

This is my first question. if happens any mistake please ignore.

We develop an inventory system using C# in visual studio, database design by MS server management and create a setup file. To access database we use ODBC.

The problem is started when we installing the setup file into another computer. After the installation clicks on the .exe file, the error will appear as shown in the image.

Most of the time it may happen because doesn't set correctly connection string, can anyone please be of any assistance,

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask